# angular2 - ngIf value is not updated in DOM

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-ng-if

I'm currently facing an issue in updating a value in the DOM.

To explain it quickly and as simple as possible, I currently have two components (A and B). B inherits from A, uses A's view as template but also inject its template into A (ng-content) so B's view is like:

```
<A>
   <template>
      <div *ngFor="let item of items" (click)="selected($event, item)">
          <span>{{item.name}}<span>
      </div>
   </template>
</A>
```

And A's view is like :

```
<ng-content select="template"></ng-content>
<div *ngIf="searching">Hey I'm looking for answer</div>
<div *ngIf="!searching">I already have my answer</div>
```

The component B has only one private variable which is the array of items and A's component has one specific method called by B which is :

```
private searching: boolean = true;

selected(event, value: any): void {
   event.stopPropagation();
   this.searching = false; // This.searching is updated in component but not in DOM
   this.selectedItem = value; // BUT this.selectedItem is updated in component AND in DOM !!
}
```

Changing this.selectedItem works, but this.searching doesn't therefore only "Yes" is displayed since searching is always TRUE.

Here is the [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/DP7K5Q63kEqXmQbRA98I?p=preview).

Can someone enlighten me please ? Thank you.

Comment: Why are you using event.stopPropagation(); ?

Comment: can you post the entire html and component code?

Comment: Here is the plunkr : https://plnkr.co/edit/DP7K5Q63kEqXmQbRA98I?p=preview

Comment: Dont get your logic. you extended current class `app`, now you have two components. to send data between components you should check this [link](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction)

Comment: Well, my components' names aren't quite relevant but... the point is : I want to create a parent component and a child component which will be used at a specific moment (ex. : a component car and a component truck. Car is like a referent to truck, despite the fact that there are functional similarities between those two, a Car is different from a Truck). I don't really want to send datas between component, but to extend the parent component to erase only a few methods from it.

Comment: @NPanda dont know more about `ng-content` what I understand is the method call is in B component so it not reflecting the variable in A component. could you check more about extends property. Up to my knowledge we can use parent method in child class so if you put `ngIf`code in B component and `select()` method in A component will work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment, method in the parent class can be used in child class so it would work, unlike you coded.I don't know more about typescript `extends` and `ng-content`. you better need to refer `extends` `ng-content` functionality and scope of the `<template-example>` .

```
 import {Component, NgModule} from '@angular/core'
    import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'
    declare var searching: boolean
    @Component({
      selector: 'my-app',
      template: `<ng-content select="template-example"></ng-content>`,
    })
    export class App {
      private searching: boolean = true;
      private selectedItem: any;

      constructor(private zone:NgZone) {
      }

      selected(event, value: any) {
        event.stopPropagation();


            this.searching = !this.searching;
      console.log(this.searching);
        this.selectedItem = value;
      }
    }


    @Component({
      selector: 'app-inheritent',
      template: `
          <my-app>
            <template-example>
              <div *ngFor="let item of items" (click)="selected($event, item)">
                <a>{{item.name}}</a>
              </div>
              <div *ngIf="!searching">
                  <span>Nope.</span>
                </div>

                <div *ngIf="searching">
                  <span>Yes</span>
                </div>
            </template-example>
          </my-app>` ,
    })
    export class AppInheritent extends App {

      private items: any = [
        {name: "1"},
        {name: "2"},
        {name: "3"},
        {name: "4"},
        {name: "5"},
      ];

      constructor() {
      }


    }

    @NgModule({
      imports: [ BrowserModule ],
      declarations: [ App, AppInheritent ],
      bootstrap: [ AppInheritent ],
      schemas: [ NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA ]
    })
    export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who could be interested... I finally found the answer thanks to @k11k2 and @Hareesh (I finally understood your answer) who enlightened me but this isn't entirely because of the extends. -- thanks.

*Extends* only confused my thoughts from the beginning.
In my example, I instantiated the component A (my-app) in my component B (app-inheritent). Because of the **extends**, I thought the component A and B would **share** the same variables and the same context but **they absolutely don't**.

In calling component B, we already have **one context** and in extending this latter with A, the two components share the same structure.

BUT, B is itself calling A so we got **another context**. A has the same structure than B but they aren't related in any way.

When I called the selected function, B actually called its PARENT selected method and not the function of the instantiated A component !

So, as @Hareesh said it, we have now multiple components. The only way to change the value is to make them communicate between each other.